# Powershell Start-job behaves differently in scheduled job than if executed manually

Tags: multithreading, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have the following Powershell code that is part of a scheduled-job:

```
#Start threaded jobs
$ScriptBlock = {
    $timeout = new-timespan -minutes 5
    $sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    while ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout){
        start-sleep -seconds 5 
        }
    if (($sw.elapsed -ge $timeout) -and $sw.IsRunning){shutdown -r -t 20}
}


"Test before job"| Out-File C:\Log.txt -Append

Start-Job $ScriptBlock -name Timeout

"Test after job"| Out-File C:\Log.txt -Append

### do whatever ###

Stop-Job -name Timeout
```

The code executes as intended when I run it manually. However if I run it as a scheduled job the Job "Timeout" executes but the script will not continue in parallel. So the job will wait for 5 minutes and restart the computer instead of executing the commands in parallel.

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Are you saying you never see the "Test after job" in the log file?

Comment: Exactly, If I run the script manually I see both lines in the log. If I run the scheduled-job the log only contains the first line.

Comment: What account are you using to schedule the job? Powershell jobs use networking (even if it's a local job), and the account you run it under must have network access.

Comment: You are right, I thought I ran the job as Administrator, but forgot to specify it.